# Why do I get this ImportError "No module named router" when it's clearly here?

Tags: python, django

when I try to run the Django server I'm treated with this error:

> ImportError "No module named router"

I have no problems with the imports, I'm sure as this problem is only when I try to work with routers, for example; viewsets in my views.py work perfectly, this means that viewsets are successfully imported and restframework is installed. Thanks!

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter


router = SimpleRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api/v2/', include('router.urls')),
]
```

Comment: And why can't I import my django app inside my project URLs config but can import it in the shell?

Comment: have you save the urls.py file. Because its saying `ImportError "No module named router"` when it should say `routers`.

Comment: Just got the error and looking into it.

Comment: Can you share tree structure of your program. Multiple things could be wrong here. __init__.py file missing in router folder. router app not included in INSTALLED_APPS list.

Comment: router app not included? it is indeed not included in the INSTALLED_APPS list.

Comment: @VikashSingh but I never read anything about including it in the installed_apps

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/23Fe3

Comment: Please add router app in installed apps list and see if it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

django rest framework official documentation says this about importing module. Read more here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api/v2/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Since you are using `'router.urls'` as string. Django is probably going and looking for a module named router which it fails to find. Because we have not imported `router` module. We have imported `SimpleRouter` class.

`router` is an object that you have created using `router = SimpleRouter()`

I hope you understood your mistake. Read more on importing routers and using them here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

Comment: How do i include router in installed_apps, do you mean the restframework?

Comment: That's how Django works. If you want to use an app you need to include it in the installed apps list. Even the 3rd party apps.

Comment: I know, so 'router' in the list would suffice? Thanks

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'router' :(

Comment: Lol. Sorry you haven't imported router you have imported SimpleRouter. I  Should have seen this earlier.

Comment: @CaptainVader2 I updated the answer. This I tried locally. Should work.

Comment: @CaptainVader2 Fixed the answer. And I am pretty sure this is the correct answer. (Although I was pretty sure last time also :D) Thanks for being patient and trying all options out. :)

Comment: @CaptainVader2 Let me know if this worked out for you ? Thanks.

Comment: Please mail me your urls.py file.  Mail is there on github. Github I'd is Vi3k6i5.